# Multicast Socket Android Error On Data Recieving?

Tags: android, network-programming, udp, broadcast, multicastsocket

I am new in socket programming. i am using Multicast socket for broadcasting through wifi hotspot network.But i am facing problem at the reciver side.
Here is my code
Server Side

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class SenderService extends Service
{
SenderThread currentSender;

public class SenderThread extends Thread
{

    public void run()
    {
        Log.d("in thread","in service");
        try
        {
            InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("224.0.0.3");
            int port=10000;
            DatagramSocket sock=new DatagramSocket();
            sock.setBroadcast(true);
            String msg="hello";
            byte []b3=new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket packet;
            b3=msg.getBytes();

            while (true)
            {   
                try
                {
                    packet = new DatagramPacket(b3, b3.length,group, port); 
                    sock.send(packet);
                    Log.d("MSG:", "sent");
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Log.d("Send Excp:", e+"");
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    sock.close();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    new SenderThread().start();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
}
```

Client Side Code

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.DatagramPacket;
 import java.net.DatagramSocket;
 import java.net.InetAddress;
 import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
 import java.net.MulticastSocket;
 import java.net.NetworkInterface;
 import java.util.Enumeration;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
 import android.net.NetworkInfo;
 import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
 import android.net.wifi.WifiManager.MulticastLock;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class ReceiverActivity extends Activity
 {
    Button b;
    Handler h;
    class MyRTh extends Thread
    {
        InetAddress group=null ;
        WifiManager wifi =    (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        MulticastLock lock = wifi.createMulticastLock("HelloAndroid");

        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                lock.acquire();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.d("lock",e+"");
            }
            try
            {
                final MulticastSocket sock=new MulticastSocket(10000);
                group= InetAddress.getByName("224.0.0.3");
                //sock.setSoTimeout(15000);
                try
                {
                    sock.joinGroup(group);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.d("join",""+e.toString());
                }
                while(true)
                {
                try
                {
                    Log.d("in try","l4");
                    byte[] data = new byte[1024]; 

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
                    Log.d("in run","l4");
                    try {
                        sock.receive(packet);
                        String s = new String(packet.getData());
                        Log.e("MSG:", "Received");
                        Log.d("msg",s);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("err",e.toString());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.d("Excp", e.toString()+"");
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
                }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_receiver);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Receiving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("1","l1");

    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonr);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            MyRTh th=new MyRTh();
            th.start();
        }
    });
}
```

}

My problem is my client side code stuck when it goes to socket.receive() method. I started my  mobile data at both sides. Started Hotspot at server side and connected to it from client.

Comment: Do they really let you indent code this poorly where you work?

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is my client side code stuck when it goes to socket.receive() method

It *blocks*.

```
InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("224.0.0.3");
```

The problem is here. Multicast addresses in the range 224.0.0.0 to 224.0.0.255 are reserved for low-level multicast support operations. Use an address in the range 224.0.1.0 to 239.255.255.255, but see also RFC 2365.

```
sock.setBroadcast(true);
```

Unnecessary. Remove. You aren't broadcasting, you are multicasting.

```
byte []b3=new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket packet;
b3=msg.getBytes();
```

You don't need to initialize `b3` when you reassign it two lines later.

```
finally
{
    sock.close();
}
```

You are closing the socket inside the `while (true)` loop. So it will send one multicast and then exit with a 'socket closed' exception, which you haven't reported here. Remove.

```
String s = new String(packet.getData());
```

That should be `new String(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength()`.

Answer (score -1):

try to set able this enable socket.setBroadcast(true);

```
    byte[] buf = new byte[256];
    packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
    socket.setBroadcast(true);
    socket.receive(packet);
```

Comment: He isn't broadcasting, he is multicasting.